# How can I chainload a USB drive from GRUB2?

Tags: boot, grub2, pxe, liveusb

I'm using GNU GRUB version 1.99-12ubuntu5, booted over the network using PXE. I used grub-mknetdir to generate the GRUB image and directory tree, which I'm serving on a TFTP server using Tftpd32 in Windows. I've put the latest version of Clonezilla on my USB drive using Tuxboot.

Right now, in GRUB's CLI, using `ls` lists only the `(pxe)` device, even if the USB drive is plugged in before the computer is on. Is there any way I can chainload Clonezilla on my USB from GRUB, which is booted over the network?

Answer (score 1):

For usb, drivers are needed. Load them with `nativedisk [drivername] [drivername2]`. When no drivername is provided, some defaults will be loaded. After this command, the disk should be listed by `ls`.